# Having trouble trying to make a board game which ranomly chooses a case and then depending on the case adds that incrimented value until 50

Tags: c++

Here is my code, this is for a school project and the rubric stipulates against the use of functions or arrays. I need help with incrementing the different card values and and asking the player to draw each time, and display the current score of the player. Thank you in advanced.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Initialize Random Seed once here!
    
    //Declare Variables
    int choose, cColor, rDraw, board, draw;//Choose
    
    //Initialize variables here
    do{
        //List of Problems which can be run by the program
        cout<<"    ****************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"    *     Welcome to Sorry!    *"<<endl;
        cout<<"    ****************************"<<endl;        
        cout<<"Enter 0 to Start Game";
        cout<<"\tEnter 1 for How To Play"<<endl;
        cout<<"       Press Any Key to Exit"<<endl;
        cin>>choose;
        
        switch(choose){
            case 0:cout<<"******************************"<<endl;
            cout<<"What color would you like to be?"<<endl;
            cout<<"1. Red"<<endl;
            cout<<"2. Blue"<<endl;
            cout<<"3. Yellow"<<endl;
            cout<<"4. Green"<<endl;
            cin>>cColor;
            switch(cColor){
            case 1: cout<<"You have chosen Red."<<endl;
                break; 
                case 2: cout<<"You have chosen Blue."<<endl;
                break;
                case 3: cout<<"You have chosen Yellow."<<endl;
                break;
                case 4:cout<<"You have chosen Green."<<endl;
                break;
                default: cout<<"ERROR Please only choose 1-4"<<endl; 
            }
            cout<<endl;
            do{
            srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); //seed the random number 
            rDraw = rand() % 11 + 1;
            if(rDraw== 1){ //this is the trouble and downwards implenting until 50 and displaying it. 
                board++;
                cout<<board;
                cout<<endl;
                cin>>draw;
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(rDraw== 2){
                board=board+2;
                     cout<<board;
                    cout<<endl;
                    cin>>draw;
                    cout<<endl;
                 break;
            }
             else if(rDraw== 3){
                 if (board== 0)
                 {
                     cout<<"Still in Start!\nYou need to draw either a 1 or 2."<<endl;
                     break;
                 }
                 else{
                     board=board+3;
                    cout<<board;
                    cout<<endl;
                    cin>>draw;
                    cout<<endl;
                 }
                 break;
            }
             else if(rDraw== 4){
                if (board== 0)
                 {
                    cout<<"Still in Start!\nYou need to draw either a 1 or 2."<<endl;
                    break;
                 }
                 else{
                    board--;
                     cout<<board;
                    cout<<endl;
                    cin>>draw;
                    cout<<endl;
                 }
                 break;
            }
             else if(rDraw== 5){
                 if (board== 0)
                 {
                     cout<<"Still in Start!\nYou need to draw either a 1 or 2."<<endl;
                     break;
                 }
                 else{
                     board=board+5;
                     cout<<board;
                    cout<<endl;
                    cin>>draw;
                    cout<<endl;
                 }
                 break;
            }
             else if(rDraw== 6){
                  if (board== 0)
                 {
                      cout<<"Still in Start!\nYou need to draw either a 1 or 2."<<endl;
                      break;
                 }
                 else{
                      board=board+7;
                cout<<board;
                cout<<endl;
                cin>>draw;
                cout<<endl;
                 }
                 break;
            }
             else if(rDraw== 7){
                 if (board== 0)
                 {
                     cout<<"Still in Start!\nYou need to draw either a 1 or 2."<<endl;
                     break;
                 }
                 else{
                     board=board+8;
                cout<<board;
                cout<<endl;
                cin>>draw;
                cout<<endl;
                 }
                 break;
            }
             else if(rDraw== 8){
                  if (board== 0)
                 {
                      cout<<"Still in Start!\nYou need to draw either a 1 or 2."<<endl;
                      break;
                 }
                 else{
                      board=board+10;
                cout<<board;
                cout<<endl;
                cin>>draw;
                cout<<endl;
                 }
                 break;
            }
             else if(rDraw== 9){
                  if (board== 0)
                 {
                      cout<<"Still in Start!\nYou need to draw either a 1 or 2."<<endl;
                      break;
                 }
                 else{
                      board=board+11;
                cout<<board;
                cout<<endl;
                cin>>draw;
                cout<<endl;
                 }
                 break;
            }
             else if(rDraw== 10){
                  if (board== 0)
                 {
                      cout<<"Still in Start!\nYou need to draw either a 1 or 2."<<endl;
                      break;
                 }
                 else{
                      board=board+12;
                cout<<board;
                cout<<endl;
                cin>>draw;
                cout<<endl;
                 }
                 break;
            }
             else{
                cout<<"11"<<endl; break;
            }
         }while(board !=50 && draw== 1);
            break;
            case 1:cout<<"Place Problem 1 here"<<endl;break;
            default:cout<<"Exiting the Menu"<<endl;
        }
    }while(choose>=0 && choose<=2);
    //Exit the program
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note : `//Initialize Random Seed once here!` I'd follow this advice. Seeding the RNG with `srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); //seed the random number` later in the program inside a loop will keep resetting the seed, skewing the RNG. Worse if you hit that `srand` fast enough, less than the resolution of `time` (almost always 1 second), you will always generate the same sequence.

Comment: Recommendation: Stop writing new code. and test what you have so far. You are being forced to write <expletive deleted>ing spaghetti code by some <expletive deleted>ing 
 lunatics, so you'll have to be extra careful. If you keep adding tho this program without ensuring what you currently have is correct, you will be adding more bugs to an already shaky foundation and the time you will have to spend debugging will increase exponentially, not linearly with each new bug.

Answer (score 0):

Excessive use of nesting is usually a bad practice.
Try to remove the hierarchy and make it as flat as possible. It will also help you to better visualize your code and catch bugs.

For these show menu-read input type of code, the [loop and a half](https://codehs.gitbooks.io/introcs/content/Basic-JavaScript-and-Graphics/loop-and-a-half.html) pattern is usually the best coding style.